# top: 'include' filter delimiter is missing

Tags: linux

I'm trying to filter top's output by command, but when I type `O`, then

```
COMMAND?apache2
```

I get the following error:

```
'include' filter delimiter is missing
```

I've looked at the top man page, but can't seem to work out what's going on.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your filter should be `COMMAND=apache`. For more information refer to [section 5e](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html) of the `top` man page, particularly the bit about 'Input Requirements'.

Answer (score 3):

To complete more the idea for other developers/users:

Correct: with `O` (shift + o) lets you to add a filter.

### What is the pattern to define a filter?

The pattern is:

- `FieldName Comparator Value`

For example in your case:

- `COMMAND=apache`

Other cases

- `USER=root`
- `%MEM>2.0`

### How I can know what are the available fields names to define a filter?

- `f`

it shows you the complete list, to exit/leave of that report, press `q`

### How I can know what is/are the current filter(s) applied? (if was/were applied)

- `Ctrl + o`

### How I can remove all the current filter(s) applied? (if was/were applied)

- `=`